# Error : near "%" : syntax error code: 5 in phonegap sqlite

Tags: sqlite, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am new to phonegap 
Can anyone pls help me out in following syntax-

```
var frm_dt=date('now', '+1 day', 'start of month');  // 1st date of month

var to_dt=date('now', '+1 month', 'start of month', '-1 day'); // last date of month

tp.executeSql('SELECT Sum(CreditVal) as CreditVal FROM ExpenseTbl where date_added  between ? and ? ;',[frm_dt,to_dt],function(tp, result) 
{ 
     if (result != null && result.rows != null) 
     {                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
         var row = result.rows.item(0); 
         ('#lblMonthlyIncm').html('');
         $('#lblMonthlyIncm').append(row.CreditVal);                                                                                             
     }                                                                                                                                                                   
},errorHandler);
```

on compiling and running on android emulator I get error -

> Error : near "%" : syntax error code: 5

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing a `$` on `('#lblMonthlyIncm').html('');`?

Comment: Thanks for Reply MBillau, but after adding $ on ('#lblMonthlyIncm').html(''); , i rebuilded the application, and now front end where result show display is displaying blank, pls help me out as its urgent ..

Comment: i got solution , i needed to change mydatabase type for Date field to form DATETIME to "Text" and then sql date range query worked out :)